# How do I install WindowsAzure.Storage in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2013

Note: this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32882103/1019042) didn't help me because I don't have the same dll: System.Collections.Immutable 1.1.37

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and .net 4.5 and following this tutorial: [Get started with Azure Blob storage using .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs)
I am trying to install WindowsAzure.Storage but get this error:

> Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Data.OData (≥ 5.8.2)'.
>   Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.Spatial (= 5.8.2)'.
>   Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Data.Edm (= 5.8.2)'.
>   Attempting to resolve dependency 'Newtonsoft.Json (≥ 6.0.8)'.
>   Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Data.Services.Client (≥ 5.8.2)'.
>   Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.Net.Requests (≥ 4.0.11)'.
>   Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync (≥ > 4.0.11)'.
>   Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.Dynamic.Runtime (≥ 4.0.0)'.
>   Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.Linq.Queryable (≥ 4.0.0)'.
>   The 'System.Linq.Queryable 4.0.0' package requires NuGet client version '3.0' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.12.0.817'.
>   [image]

when I upgrade Nuget per the red error in the image, it takes me to Extensions and Updates asking to update this:
[image]

I don't know the relation between what I am looking for and this, but I went ahead and followed that update anyway, but get the error:
[image]

Where should I proceed from here!?

based on comment form Simsons, I already checked that my processor supports Virtualization:
[image]

Comment: Looks like you have Virtualization disabled on your PC or not supported by processor, check if it is enabled by following steps from https://www.technorms.com/8208/check-if-processor-supports-virtualization

Comment: my processor have virtualization, I updated answer with that info.

Comment: Which version of windows do you have?

Answer (score 13):

When you try to install the WindowsAzure.Storage package through NuGet, this is the key error;

> Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.Linq.Queryable (≥ 4.0.0)'. The 'System.Linq.Queryable 4.0.0' package requires NuGet client version '3.0' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.12.0.817'

Unfortunately, System.Linq.Queryable **4.0.0** requires NuGet 3.0 or above. So this isn't going to work on Visual Studio 2013.

Luckily, the newer System.Linq.Queryable **4.3.0** only requires NuGet 2.12 which *is* available for Visual Studio 2013.

So, to successfully install WindowsAzure.Storage in Visual Studio 2013 via NuGet:

1. Download and Install NuGet 2.12 if you don't already have it. (OP has confirmed already having this version)
2. In NuGet, Install [System.Linq.Queryable 4.3.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Queryable/4.3.0)
3. In NuGet, Install [WindowsAzure.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage)

Answer (score 1):

Open your Visual Studio 2013. Go to **Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console**

In the packet manager console type:

```
Install-Package NuGet.Client -Version 3.2.0
```

I tried this using NuGet Client version 3.2.0. The current latest version is 4.3 (beta) or 4.2. So I'm not sure if it will work for versions 4.2 and 4.3, but it surely works for NuGet 3.2.0. NuGet >3 was all I needed for SendGrid and other packages.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly for Visual Studio 2013 you can only use NuGet 2.12,

https://www.nuget.org

If you want to use NuGet 3.x as well as those packages that require NuGet 3.x, you have to upgrade to Visual Studio 2015 and above.

Comment: And it's getting worse every day. It's already impossible to install [Json.NET 10.0.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/10.0.2) on VS earlier than 2015 (fails with the ["'X' already has a dependency defined for 'Y'"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25725545/11683) error).

Comment: so if I can't afford getting 2015 subscription at least, I am out of luck, is this a correct statement?

Comment: Microsoft technical support for VS 2013 and NuGet 2.x would last for 10 years, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17959/lifecycle-policy-faq-microsoft-developer-tools and https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search/18649 but the limitation you hit was set by package owners, not Microsoft. So you would have to request assistance from the package owners, or develop your own fork, or use an old version of that package. Of course, the simplest approach is to buy latest Visual Studio.

Comment: @GSerg Some folks on our team are still using Visual Studio 2013 Update 5, and I believe that supports nuget 2.12 and Json.NET 10.0.3.

Comment: @ScottKoland I stand corrected. It's come to my attention that was VS 2012.