# Xamarin Forms "Todo DocumentDB" sample - Higher version than referenced assembly System.Collections.Specialized error

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2013, xamarin.forms, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and can't seem to fix the following build error that I get when I go to https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WebServices/TodoDocumentDB/ and download the sample code and attempt to run it:

```
Error   2   Assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core, Version=1.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' uses 
'System.Collections.Specialized, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced 
assembly 'System.Collections.Specialized, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'    c:\Users\Elijah  
Lofgren\Downloads\T1mobio\TodoDocumentDB\packages\Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Cr
e.1.0.0\lib\netstandard1.6\Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core.dll  
TodoDocumentDB.Droid
```

I've tried updating all the nuget packages but that hasn't worked.

I can't seem to find anyone else with this error.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you trie to change System.Collections.Specialized to 4.0.1.0 in the package.json file & restore nuget ?

Comment: I edited the packages.config files and changed <package id="System.Collections.Specialized" version="4.0.0.0" to   <package id="System.Collections.Specialized" version="4.0.1"  but now I get this error: "Error 2 NuGet Package restore failed for project TodoDocumentDB.Droid: The 'System.Collections.Specialized 4.0.0' package requires NuGet client version '3.0' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.12.0.817'" - looks like Nuget 3.0 won't work with VS 2013: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43532106/908677 - maybe getting this working in VS 2013 is impossible.

Comment: That's what I thought, the last ToDo sample is not compatible with VS 2013, you should use Xamarin Studio or VS 2015 and above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this code is not compatible with Visual Studio 2013 on PC.

On PC, you need to use Visual Studio 2015 (or newer).

On Mac, you can use any version of Visual Studio for Mac.